# How to handle multiple url calls using global driver with selenium web driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a function that returns a webdriver as a singleton (only instantiate once AND global_driver is a global variable):

```
global_driver = None
...
def getDriver():
    global global_driver
    if not global_driver:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        global_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        return global_driver
    else:
        return global_driver
```

and another function that properly closes and quits the driver:

```
def quitDriver():
    global global_driver
    global_driver.close()
    global_driver.quit()
    global_driver = None
```

I have another function that calls `getDriver()` to parse a url:

```
def clickQuarterlyButton(url):
    driver = getDriver()
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, constants.SLEEP_TIME).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[1]/div[2]/button'))).click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup
```

I call the `clickQuarterlyButton(url)` function in a for loop like this for multiple urls:

```
for url in urls:
    clickQuarterlyButton(url)
    quitDriver()
```

I want to create a new instance of web driver to read and parse for each url to avoid multi threading issues but I am still running into multi threading issues. What is the right way to set up the webdriver to handle multiple urls?